# I'm trying to read content from a file but I'm not getting exact output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

```
while read -r line 

do

    echo $line

done <<< $(cat $input_file)
```

Here I'm trying to read the input from the input file whose path is passed through command line.

The contents of the file are -

```
30 08 10 06 * pwd
30 09 10 06 * pwd
```

When I'm trying to print the line I have read , I'm getting all the files present in the pwd(present working directory) instead of `*`. What should I do ?

Comment: use echo "$line"

Comment: The `cat` is not necessary here. You can use `< $input_file` instead of `<<< $(cat $input_file)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What should I do ?

Quote variable expansions.

```
echo "$line"
```

The unquoted result of variable expansion `$line` undergoes [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) which causes `*` to expand to list of filenames. A quoted variable expansion doesn't undergo word splitting not filename expansion. As rule of a thumb, if you write `$`, you should put it inside `"`.

Note:

- `<<<$(cat $input_file)` is like `echo $(echo $(echo something)))`. Just `< $input_file` - there is no need to execute a process `cat` to read from file, then save the result of that process execution into a temporary variable `$(..)` into and then finally redirect that temporary buffer into stdin of a process `<<<`. Just redirect the file.
- Read [bashfaq how to read a file line by line](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and remember to check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net